# JavaScript object behaving weird

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attaching an image where I can see that the entities property of object is an array with 100 elements. But when I expand it shows 201. And actually it is an array of length 201 only. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: because `count` is the element stored in your object

Comment: because `console` is async, and on expand try show actual information

Comment: Oh! that helps, I did not know it was async. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you console log for chrome what it outputs is what the object looks like as soon as it hits that piece of code. If you expand the object at a later time it could have changed.

```
var myObject = { test: 4, [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] }
console.log(myObject);
myObject.test = 5;
```

Drop this into the chrome console and expand the object to see what I mean. It will show '4' when it's closed but '5' when it's opened.